# Is the Enumeration class a good way to represent database data in code?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

For the application I am currently working on we need a way to represent the Permissions that live in the database in code so that we are able to perform various actions throughout the request lifecycle.

We are currently implementing the Enumeration base class as outlined in the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types). I just wanted to know if there is a better way to handle something like this outside of a normal enum since we'd like access to more than just the id like you'd get in an enum.

Also, is there a good way to keep this data in sync?

Our implementation would look like:

```cs
public partial class ServiceConstant : Enumeration
{
    public Guid PublicId { get; }
    public ServiceType Type { get; }

    public static readonly ServiceConstant Permission1 =
        new(1250, "BE84DB4A-1450-42A8-A097-F2715194D745", ServiceType.Category.Id, "Permission One");

    public static readonly ServiceConstant Permission2 =
        new(1251, "B123DEAG-1450-42A8-A094-F2715194D742", ServiceType.Service.Id, "Permission Two");
    // and so on/so forth for each service (permission)

    private ServiceConstant(int id, string publicId, int serviceTypeId, string name, string description = null)
        : base(id, name, description)
    {
        PublicId = Guid.Parse(publicId);
        Type = FromValue<ServiceType>(serviceTypeId);
    }
    
    public static ServiceConstant FromPublicId(Guid publicId) {
        var matchingItem = GetAll<ServiceConstant>()
            .FirstOrDefault(s=>s.PublicId == publicId);
        return matchingItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: We use this in our application and it works just fine.  If you use the enum to populate database records (maybe some static seed data), then you must create a new migration each time you add a new enumeration value.

Comment: @Neil I appreciate the quick reply. Yeah I plan on using it to seed the permission data whenever I finishing writing all of them. 

Does your class match the database record entirely, i.e. each column of the table represented as a property on the class or do you just have like the id/name?

Comment: It doesn't match entirely, but pretty close.  Sometimes we even have a foreign key to another enumeration type too (e.g. we have a 'claims' enumeration (things like 'Country' or 'Gender') and also Country and Gender enumerations, which links back to the claim it belongs to.

Comment: One thing to mention though, is that we use the enumeration for seeding data, but we still search the database, instead of just using the enumeration.   e.g. We find the database record for the public id, rather than finding the enumeration value.  The reason for this, is that ultimately, the database may eventually stray from the enumerations (e.g. we may manually add a new country to the database, and not to the enumeration).

Comment: @Neil Makes sense. That was/is one of my concerns is that there's no strict binding between the database and the enumeration class, but I guess there really is no way around that. Only thing I am curious about is that if you use the enumeration to seed the database, but it doesn't match the table entirely, what do you do about the missing values? Or does your seeding method populate them?

Comment: The EF database configuration includes calls to `.HasData` which includes any updates as part of the migration.

Comment: @Neil I am having a little bit of difficulty following. Are you instantiating a new entity for each enumeration and setting the properties of the entity to that of the enumeration in the `.HasData()` or am I misunderstanding? If you could provide a small example that would be great! thanks